# Activator.CreateInstance returning error now

Tags: c#

I was initially using the following method - which was working fine

```
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance("MyProject","MyProject.MyImpl");
```

Now I am getting an error at the above line and the error is:

```
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

Any suggestions on what might be going wrong ?

Comment: Well if you look at the inner exception, it will probably tell you what's wrong. Always look at *all* the information in an exception.

Comment: `MyImpl` is throwing an exception in its constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest would be to set a breakpoint in the constructor of the `MyImpl` class and debug it.

One tricky problem you might be having is if the exception is actually not thrown directly by the constructor, but by some field initializer.

For example the following would cause the behavior you described, even though there is no explicit constructor that could throw anything.

```
public class MyImpl
{
    private int something = ThisMethodThrows();

    private int ThisMethodThrows()
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

An exception is being thrown in the constructor of the object. [Turn exceptions on in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx) and it should break when that constructor throws.